# How can you enable GTK3 themes' dark theme mode when using Unity 7?

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, gtk, numix

When using GTK3 themes on GNOME, *GNOME Tweak Tool* has an option to enable *'Global Dark Theme'*. With Numix GTK theme, it produces this look:
[image: Numix with dark theme mode enabled on GNOME]

With *Unity 7*, when you use *Unity Tweak Tool* to change the theme from Ambiance to Numix, there is no way to enable the dark theme mode. The result looks like this:
[image: Numix on Unity 7]

Is there a way I can make Numix in *Unity 7* look like it does in GNOME when the *'Global Dark Theme'* option is checked in GNOME Tweak Tool?

Answer (score 13):

You can enable *'Global Dark Theme'* mode on *Unity 7*, the same way it's enabled on *Gnome Shell*. Just install **GNOME Tweak Tool** by clicking here:
[image: Install GNOME Tweak Tool]

Or run this in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

When it's installed, open *Tweak Tool* from the Dash and toggle on *'Global Dark Theme'* switch as shown below:

[image: GNOME Tweak Tool]

From now on you can use the dark mode of themes under *Unity 7* the same way you use them on GNOME! If it's not working, just check if the theme implements GNOME's dark theme mode.

### Manual Method

GNOME Tweak Tool and most of the options it provides are tailored for *Gnome Shell* and so may not work as intended on *Unity*. Coz of this, many users prefer not to install GNOME Tweak Tool and choose *Unity Tweak Tool* over it. If for any reason you don't wanna install GNOME Tweak Tool, this is how you can enable the *'Global Dark Theme'* mode manually:

**Step 1**: Open the GTK3 configuration file in Text Editor:

```
gedit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

**Step 2**: Paste this into the file opened by Text Editor:

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

and save it. That's all! Enjoy your dark themes

Comment: HEXcube, this is all very helpful, thank you! If I can just ask one more thing and you'll have solved my entire issue: how can you apply the dark theme to gtk 2.0 applications? with gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1, I can see my gtk 3.0 apps are now dark, but apps like Gimp, Inkscape, VLC player, etc. are still light. How can I get those to follow suit?

Comment: @Jesse GNOME's _'Global Dark Theme'_ mode is applicable ONLY to GTK3 apps. GTK2 can't turn the dark mode on and off. So you'll need to specifically apply a GTK theme whose GTK2 part is dark. Current versions of **GIMP**, **InkScape** and **LibreOffice** are all GTK2, but the GTK3 versions are in development. Qt based apps (including **VLC**) follow the GTK2 theme when running on GNOME based desktops.